# Check for errors, but don't show them

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have a tiny script for killing some processes. It works fine except when a process is not found it show the error message. Adding `2 > nul` won't solve the problem because the error is discarded ...

How to prevent the error from showing, and show some meanningful message?

```
for %%i in (%procs%) do (
    TASKKILL /F /IM %%i > nul
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        echo %%i was stopped successfully
        echo.
    ) else (
        echo %%i was not started
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the syntax used for `errorlevel` checking (the expression `if errorlevel n` means *if errorlevel is equal or greater to n* )

```dos
for %%i in (%procs%) do (
    >nul 2>&1 TASKKILL /F /IM "%%~i" 
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%i was stopped successfully
    ) else (
        echo %%i was not started
    )
)
```

Using conditional execution operators (`&&` = execute if the previous command was successful, `||` = execute if the previous command failed)

```dos
for %%i in (%procs%) do (
    >nul 2>&1 TASKKILL /F /IM "%%~i" && (
        echo %%i was stopped successfully
    ) || (
        echo %%i was not started
    )
)
```

Using delayed expansion (without it, with the `errorlevel` read operation replaced with the value inside the variable when the full block was parsed, you can not retrieve the changed value)

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (%procs%) do (
    >nul 2>&1 TASKKILL /F /IM "%%~i" 
    if !errorlevel!==0 (
        echo %%i was stopped successfully
    ) else (
        echo %%i was not started
    )
)
```

But remember all this samples are a simplification. Ex. `taskkill` can also fail if the process can not be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Read [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables can
>   be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal
>   `%variable_name%`).

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (%procs%) do (
    TASKKILL /F /IM %%i 1>nul 2>&1
    if "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
        echo %%i was stopped successfully
        echo.
    ) else (
        echo %%i was not started
    )
)
```

or

```
for %%i in (%procs%) do (
    TASKKILL /F /IM %%i 1>nul 2>&1
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        echo %%i was not started
    ) else (
        echo %%i was stopped successfully
        echo.
    )
)
```

Note that `TASKKILL` command could fail for more reasons, not only for that a process is not runninq, e.g. if you are trying to kill an elevated process from an unelevated `cmd` prompt.